# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row But I need multiple rows in inner query?

Tags: sql, oracle

This SQL works will work for me if it can return multiple rows ? how to rewrite sql so it should work with NVL2, My input parameter is 127,147

```
SELECT * 
FROM org_organization_definitions ORG 
where organization_code IN      
                    NVL2(:p_org_code, (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (:p_org_code, 
                                                       '[^,]+', 
                                                       1, 
                                                       LEVEL) 
                                   FROM DUAL 
                             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (:p_org_code, 
                                                       '[^,]+', 
                                                       1, 
                                                       LEVEL) 
                                           IS NOT NULL),organization_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the logic in a different way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM org_organization_definitions ORG 
where organization_code = :p_org_code or
      (:p_org_code is null and
       organization_code IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:p_org_code, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
                             FROM DUAL 
                             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:p_org_code, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                            )
      ) or 
      not exists (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(:p_org_code, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
                  FROM DUAL 
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(:p_org_code, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a LEFT JOIN, as below:

```
SELECT ORG.* 
FROM org_organization_definitions ORG 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (:p_org_code, 
                                                       '[^,]+', 
                                                       1, 
                                                       LEVEL) org_code
                                   FROM DUAL 
                             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (:p_org_code, 
                                                       '[^,]+', 
                                                       1, 
                                                       LEVEL) 
                                           IS NOT NULL) modified_org_codes
ON ORG.organization_code = modified_org_codes.org_code;
```